# Meteor and D3: d3.event is null

Tags: meteor, d3.js

I'm a beginner with meteor and D3 and currently I'm trying to get one of the examples of M. Bostock (adapted to a map of UK and Europe) to work.
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675
Creating an showing the map works perfectly, but when clicking or trying to zoom, following errors occur:
[Errors after click or zoom, d3.event is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb6eE.png)

Surprisingly everything works as expected when starting this example with http-server (http-server -p 8008 &).

I know that d3 removes the event variable after finishing the event ([d3.event is null inside of debounced function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773113/d3-event-is-null-inside-of-debounced-function)), but I don't know if this could also cause this behaviour in Meteor (and how to solve it here)
Can anyone give me a hint, why d3.event is always null within Meteor and how to handle this issue?

I'm using following Meteor packages:

```
meteor add d3js:d3
meteor add garrilla:topojson
```

Here's my HTML:

```html
<head>
 <title>Map</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1 id="header-title">Title</h1>
 </header>


 <div id="vis-and-sidebar">
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="fixed-footer"></div>

 <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
 <script>

 var visElem = d3.select("#vis");

  var width = visElem.node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
  height = visElem.node().getBoundingClientRect().height,
  active = d3.select(null);

  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale(550)
  .translate([270, 1010]);

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .translate([0, 0])
  .scale(1)
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

  var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("click", stopped, true);

  console.log("SVG-Objekt zum Zeichnen:");
  console.log(svg);

  svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "background")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("click", reset);

  var g = svg.append("g");

  svg
    .call(zoom) // delete this line to disable free zooming
    .call(zoom.event);

    d3.json("europe.json", function(error, europe) {
      if (error) throw error;

      g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.subunits).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "feature")
      .on("click", clicked);

      g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(europe, europe.objects.subunits, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "mesh")
      .attr("d", path);
    });

    function clicked(d) {
      if (active.node() === this) return reset();
      active.classed("active", false);
      active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

      var bounds = path.bounds(d),
      dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

      svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
    }

    function reset() {
      active.classed("active", false);
      active = d3.select(null);

      svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate([0, 0]).scale(1).event);
    }

    function zoomed() {
     console.log(d3.event);
     g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
     g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
   }

// If the drag behavior prevents the default click,
// also stop propagation so we don’t click-to-zoom.
function stopped() {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) d3.event.stopPropagation();
}

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the D3 package as well as referencing D3 with the script-tag caused this issue. When removing the script-tag, every event object contains the expected values.